# nodeSelector not working 1.2.0

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
  nodeSelector:
    docker: twelve
```

On the kube master:

```
kubectl get nodes -l docker=twelve
NAME           LABELS                                              STATUS    AGE
10.10.1.4   docker=twelve,kubernetes.io/hostname=10.10.1.4   Ready     115d
10.10.1.5   docker=twelve,kubernetes.io/hostname=10.10.1.5   Ready     115d
```

from the event log

```
4m          17s        20        busybox                          Pod                                                         FailedScheduling         {scheduler }                Failed for reason MatchNodeSelector and possibly others
```

If I remove the nodeSelector, it deploys w/o issue.
I am trying to handle docker 1.9.1 and docker 1.12.1 for various teams and this is preventing it.
This is a kube cluster on CentOS 7.2.-1511 servers

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"86327329213fed4af2661c5ae1e92f9956b24f55", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"86327329213fed4af2661c5ae1e92f9956b24f55", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the kube-scheduler fixed the issue.

I guess when you add a new label to a node, you need to restart the scheduler.